# how to store the contact us form data in the google forms for my website

Tags: contacts, google-forms, google-contacts-api

I would like to store the contact us form data in my google form. I have created contact us form in my webpage and copied the google form link in my form link. Kindly tell the steps to make the form work
Here the code that I have written

```
  <div class="form-group">
 <form action="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSedlnzPGGIwjq_C3W0KCev-WexWs6SFdf7nk0sWT3v2wP6fA/viewform?usp=sf_link" class="comment-form contact-form" novalidate="novalidate">
 <input type="text"  class="form-control" placeholder="Name" name="name">
<input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="Mail Address" name="email">
<textarea name="message"  class="form-control" placeholder="Comment"></textarea>
 <button type="submit" class="contact-us thm-btn"><span>Post Now</span></button>
</form>
```

My google form link is placed n the action which is https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSedlnzPGGIwjq_C3W0KCev-WexWs6SF-df7nk0sWT3v2wP6fA/viewform?usp=sf_link

Answer (score 0):

The google form data is accessible via google sheets.
You also have the ability to create a trigger that will do something with the data when the form is posted, more information on this can be found at.
https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/editor-triggers